# Socket.Select with PowerShell gives error

Tags: sockets, select, powershell

I am attempting to write a TCP server with PowerShell.

It seems to work fine up to the Select call:

```
$clients = @()
$socket = New-Object System.Net.Sockets.Socket([System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily]::InterNetwork, [System.Net.Sockets.SOcketType]::Stream, [System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType]::Tcp)
$socket.Bind((New-Object System.Net.IPEndPoint ([system.net.ipaddress]::any, $port)))
$socket.Listen(10)
$clients += $socket
[System.Net.Sockets.Socket]::Select($clients, $null, $null, -1)
```

this gives the following error message:

```
The operation is not allowed on objects of type System.Management.Automation.PSObject. Use only objects of type System.Net.Sockets.Socket.
```

I assume this is because of PowerShell wrapping up its objects? Just not sure why it fails with `Select` where it succeeds elsewhere, or how to get around it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, PowerShell has a tendency to wrap objects especially in V2 IIRC.  Create a List specifically e.g.:

```
$clients = new-object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Net.Sockets.Socket]
...
$clients.Add($socket)
[System.Net.Sockets.Socket]::Select($clients, $null, $null, -1)
```

You could also try a cast e.g.:

```
[System.Net.Sockets.Socket]::Select([System.Collections.IList]$clients, $null, $null, -1)
```

Comment: of course :P that would make sense. is Select just too old to be able to account for this?

Comment: No it is not a .NET issue.  It is an issue with PowerShell's extended type system.  .NET arrays implement IList and you've created an array and populated it with a Socket object.  It's just the wrapping inside a psobject that is not working with the .NET method call.